# Websocket handshake status 426

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a tornado server listening at port 9000, but when I try to create a connection from websocket-client, I am getting the following error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "XXX", line 879, in custom_func
        ws = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:9000/")
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket.py", line 110, in create_connection
        websock.connect(url, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket.py", line 210, in connect
        self._handshake(hostname, port, resource, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket.py", line 246, in _handshake
        raise WebSocketException("Handshake Status %d" % status)
```

**WebSocketException: Handshake Status 426**

In tornado, 426 means Upgrade required. I've already upgraded my client but I still get the same error.
Here is my pip freeze:

```
tornado==3.1
websocket-client==0.4
```

I am using the following import:

```
from websocket import create_connection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client/blob/v0.4.0/websocket.py#L169) you can see that `websocket-client` implements Websocket protocol draft 76.
Also, notice that 0.4 is three years old.  [0.12](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/0.12.0) is the latest version.

[This](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/v3.1.0/tornado/websocket.py#L145) is where you are getting the 426 from.

You need to override the [WebSocketHandler.allow_draft76](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.allow_draft76) method.

Comment: strangely, pip wasn't fetching the latest version for me. I had to download from git and run setup.py install